# C# priorityQueue Dequeue return type

Tags: c#, .net, priority-queue

C# .Net have priorityQueue library which I used like this

```
PriorityQueue<char, int> q = new PriorityQueue<char, int>();
q.Enqueue('c', 1);
q.Dequeue(); // only printc 'c'
```

I looked in the ms document to find out a way to be able to print 'c' priority (i.e: 1) but haven't found any. Am I missing something obvious?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use [TryDequeue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.priorityqueue-2.trydequeue?view=net-6.0#system-collections-generic-priorityqueue-2-trydequeue(-0@-1@)) it will remove the element, and copies it and its associated priority to the element and priority arguments.

```
q.TryDequeue(out var element, out var priority)
```